# How can I discard rows that are out of order?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table below, and the _date dictates the primary order. For this particular application, the _value should always *decrease* with time, however sometimes there are anomalies and I want to get rid of those.

```
drop table if exists #x
create table #x (_id int identity, _application_id int, _date datetime, _value int)
insert into #x values (1, '2022-10-01', 150)
insert into #x values (1, '2022-10-03', 100)
insert into #x values (1, '2022-10-04', 200)
insert into #x values (1, '2022-10-06', 190)
insert into #x values (1, '2022-10-08', 90)
insert into #x values (1, '2022-10-10', 50)
insert into #x values (2, '2022-10-01', 150)
insert into #x values (2, '2022-10-02', 140)
insert into #x values (2, '2022-10-05', 999)
insert into #x values (2, '2022-10-06', 130)
insert into #x values (2, '2022-10-07', 120)
insert into #x values (2, '2022-10-08', 100)
insert into #x values (3, '2022-10-01', 150)
insert into #x values (3, '2022-10-09', 200)
insert into #x values (3, '2022-10-11', 250)
```

I can use lag() to easily find the first entry that goes up instead of down:

```
select *, 
case when _value > lag(_value) over (partition by _application_id order by _date) then 1 else 0 end as _error
from #x 
order by _application_id, _date
```

I can put that in a cte or subquery and filter where _error = 0, but the remaining entries could still be out of order since we're only comparing each _value to the previous one. Lines 4, 10 and 11 from the query above should be flagged.

I could of course delete and re-query multiple times until no _error's show up, but I'm trying to avoid recursion or moving this to a stored procedure. I was also trying to think of a way to hold the last descending value constant and compare that to subsequent rows until we find the next lesser entry, but I can't see an easy way to do that. The desired output is below.

```
_id  _application_id  _date         _value
1    1                2022-10-01    150
2    1                2022-10-03    100
5    1                2022-10-08    90
6    1                2022-10-10    50
7    2                2022-10-01    150
8    2                2022-10-02    140
12   2                2022-10-08    100
13   3                2022-10-01    150
```

I'm using the latest version of SQL Server. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the running minimum window function to keep track with the last minimum value over the increasing of date as the following:

```
SELECT _id, _application_id, _date, _value
FROM
(
  SELECT *,
    MIN(_value) OVER (PARTITION BY _application_id ORDER BY _date) mn
  FROM #x
) T
WHERE _value=mn
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ns0E_2kr).

Comment: That's an elegant and efficient solution.

Comment: Agree with @GMB, that's pretty slick. In fact, I don't even need the outer query -- subbing the errant increasing values with the previous minimum value (as shown if you run the subquery by itself) will work for this particular application. Thank you.